# Suggestbox returning suggestions that begin AND contain the user's input

Tags: java, gwt, suggestbox

I am using a SuggestBox and I am having some difficulties to obtain the good behavior of my application.

Consider the following list of suggestions :

```
1. lol 
2. good evening
3. goodbye
4. end 
5. saluti
```

If I use my SuggestBox with this list and I type "g" I will obtain :

```
1. good evening
2. goodbye
```

It I type "e" :

```
1. good evening
2. end
```

But what I want to obtain is the words containing the input and not only the ones beginning with the input. For example if I type "l", I want to obtain :

```
1. lol
2. saluti
```

and not only :

```
1. lol
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SuggestBox is using a [SuggestOracle](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestOracle.html) to decide what to return given some input. The default oracle for a SuggestBox is [MultiWordSuggestOracle](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MultiWordSuggestOracle.html) that has the behaviour you describe. If you want some other behaviour, you will have to write your own oracle by extending SuggestOracle. [Check out this](http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/building-an-autocompletion-on-gwt-with-rpc-contextlistener-and-a-suggest-tree-part-0/) very good blog tutorial on how to implement autocompletion in GWT.

Comment: Tank you for your answer, I will check out your link.